# Task List Board issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I've been having quite the ruckus with this. I'm a newbie to JavaScript and I've got a mission to build a task list board where the user types in a task to do with date and time, and when submitted, the task along with the date and time appear inside a photo using JavaScript. I've managed to make the photo appear when I click on "Submit" but I've faced a few issues:

1. The text, date and time do not appear inside the photo. The page says "[object HTMLInputElement]"
2. In the HTML, I've made the input for the text, date and time "required" but when I click "Submit" it just goes through.

```js
function dd(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

let output = "";
function addTask() {
    output = `<div><img src="/assets/images/notebg.png" alt="Sticky Note"></div>`
    let mainDiv = dd("main-page").innerHTML += output
}
```

```html
<main id="main-page">
<div class="myForm">
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="task" class="inputs" placeholder="Enter your task here" required>
        <br>
        <input type="date" id="date" class="inputs" placeholder="Enter the date here" required>
        <br>
        <input type="time" id="time" class="inputs" placeholder="Enter the time here" required>
        <br>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addTask()">
        <input class="btn btn-warning" type="reset" value="Reset">
    </form>
</div>
</main>
<div class="my-notes" id="myNotes">
    <p id="newNotes"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even attempt do anything with the input values. How exactly are you expecting those values to be included?

Comment: Also, what is the `mainDiv` variable meant to do?

Comment: You need to get the input values first. You can get that by using for ex dateValue = document.getElementById('date').value, for task taskValue = document.getElementById('task').value, for time timeValue = document.getElementById('time').value

Comment: You can add these Ids as parameters in your dd function and make it get the inputs value

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're encountering involves several aspects of JavaScript and HTML form handling. To address the problems step by step:

Prevent Default Form Submission Behavior: When you use an  within a form, clicking it will by default submit the form, causing the page to reload or navigate away. To prevent this, you need to stop the default action. This can be done by modifying your addTask function to accept the event as a parameter and calling event.preventDefault().

Displaying Text, Date, and Time Inside the Photo: You're creating a div with an img tag but not actually including the input values inside it. You need to fetch the values from your input elements and then integrate them into your output string.

Issue with *"[object HTMLInputElement]":* This message appears because you're trying to concatenate an element object directly to your HTML without accessing its value. You need to access the value property of your input elements.

**JavaScript**

```
function dd(x) {
    return document.getElementById(x);
}

function addTask(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form from submitting normally

    // Get values from inputs
    const taskValue = dd("task").value;
    const dateValue = dd("date").value;
    const timeValue = dd("time").value;

    // Create output string with task, date, and time
    output = `<div><img src="/assets/images/notebg.png" alt="Sticky Note"><p>${taskValue}</p><p>${dateValue}</p><p>${timeValue}</p></div>`;

    // Append new content
    let mainDiv = dd("main-page");
    mainDiv.innerHTML += output;
}
```

**HTML**
Change the onclick attribute of your submit button to include return and modify its type to button to prevent form submission. Then, add an id to your submit button for the event listener:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
```

You could also keep it as type="submit" and handle the form submission via JavaScript more directly, but changing it to button and handling the click event as shown simplifies things for this example.

Finally, ensure you attach your event listener correctly in the JavaScript. If you decide to keep the button as type="submit", you would need to attach an event listener to the form's submit event and prevent its default action as shown above. If you switch to type="button", you can directly add an onclick attribute or better, add an event listener in your JavaScript file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', addTask);
});
```